# Symbolising options for ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-online

I have a county polygon. In it, I have a field (column) that is either yes or no. There are 100 rows to the attribute table and 75% of the attributes are yes, 25% are No. 
Is there a way I can symbolise this in ArcGIS Online? I was thinking of a pie chart, where the user would click on the county polygon and it would show 3/4 Yes (Green) and 1/4 No (Red). If it would be possible to click on that chart to bring up a pop-up, that would be even better.

Comment: Hi MapGeo, did you manage this eventually? Could you post your solution? thanks!